# Postgresql composite unique keys (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName) not working?

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel, unique

I have the following schema in Laravel (postgresql)

```
Schema::create('members', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('mname')->nullable();
        $table->string('ename', 10)->nullable();

        $table->unique(array('lname', 'fname', 'mname'));
    });
```

As you notice, I have a composite unique key composed of `lname`, `fname`, and `mname`. However I have set `mname` to `nullable()` since not all people have a middle name.

But, when adding data to the database (postgresql)

```
DB::table('students')->insert(
    array(
        array(
            'lname' => 'Last 1',
            'fname' => 'First 1'
        ),
        array(
            'lname' => 'Last 1',
            'fname' => 'First 1'
        )
    )
);
```

It saved successfully! Am I doing wrong? What's the workaround for this? Please help.

Comment: Please show the actual table and constraints generated by your ORM / whatever abstraction tool, and the *actual SQL* run as a result of your insert command. To get the table definition connect with `psql` and run `\dt members`. For the SQL, fish it out of whatever your ORM query log is.

Comment: Please read http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ and reconsider this schema.

Comment: @CraigRinger very good article but I believe he need to understand the concept of NULLS a little bit better. Using names as keys is going to burn you badly at some point. However don't deny a person the privilege of struggle and experience right?

Comment: What happens when you try to insert another guy called John Smith?

Answer (score 3):

Remember the basic rule:

`NULL!= NULL or NULL <> NULL`

Even though both have a `NULL` value they cannot be compared because they are undefined. `NULL` does not equal nothing. `NULL` equals undefined. Think about it like this a `NULL` is like Chuck Norris because nothing can be compared to Chuck Norris.

Thus your keys:

```
Last1 NULL First1
Last1 NULL First1
```

Are unique as the `NULLS` are not comparable.

To get this to work default a `NULL` middle name to a `''` string or zero length string.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: the correct term would be *unknown* rather than *undefined*. For three value logic: true, false, *unknown*.

Comment: @Denis yes unknown is correct but then the Chuck Norris comparison does not work that well.